# Почему не назначается атрибут?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть ссылки которые генерируются динамически на `angular` через `ng-repeat`.
Классы через `ng-class`. Вот код:

```
        <a class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="locateTo($event,data)" ng-class="{'btn-danger':data.select}">
            <span>{{data.title}}</span>
        </a>
```

Необходимо чтобы элементов с классом (генерируется через `ng-class`) `p90` (они отображаются), был атрибут `ng-click` равный `false`.

Comment: p90 Откуда берется,из ng-repeat?если можно приведите код с силками и с ng-repeat.а там уже можно ng-if написать.
<div ng-if='p90' ng-click='false'>aaa</div>

Comment: а зачем? почему просто не проверить **внутри функции locateTo**?

Comment: Да точно.Согласен.Правильней проверять в ней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял что надо проверять `data.select`.
Если нет, то подставьте вместо него свою переменную.

**[ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)**

```
<div ng-switch on="data.select">
    <a ng-switch-when='p90' class="btn btn-mini" ng-class="{'btn-danger':data.select}">
        <span>{{data.title}}</span>
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="locateTo($event,data)" ng-class="{'btn-danger':data.select}">
        <span>{{data.title}}</span>
    </a>
    <div ng-switch-default>default</div>
</div>
```

Ну или тут товарищ *@Grundy* правильно посоветовал - проверять в функции `locateTo` `data.select` на равенство `p90` и возвращать соответствующее значение.

Comment: Через switch пока что не получается (angular знаю на среднем уровне). А все остальные способы, заменяют ng-click у всех элементов

Comment: а data.select возвращает true или false

Comment: @Misha Spring Я предполагаю что data.select p90.
if(data.select == 'p90') return false else 'что вы хотите '
Вы тут мало разъясняете ,поэтому приходится предполагать

Comment: Спасибо. Вместо data.select в switch, нужно было подставить data.style